# I2C and Picamera

Tags: raspberry-pi2, i2c

I have connected a RTC and pi camera with raspberry pi. I suppose that both communicate with Raspi via I2C bus. But when I do " sudo i2cdetect -y 1"
only RTC is detected not the camera. How it is possible? Please help, what i am not clear with or what might be the problem.

Comment: the pi camera is connected via CSI connector and might not show up as a i2c device. Have a look at the [pi-camera Python package](http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.3/quickstart.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I came to know that there are two I2C buses in raspi revison 2. I2C 1 is dedicated for GPIO pins 3 and 4. Whereas I2C 0 is deticated for CSI port as well as GPIO pins 27 and 28.